# Email list database design

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

What is an efficient way to store sent emails for a email list database? I'm having some trouble figuring it out.

Right now, to simplify I have something like this:

```
Lists:
ID,
Name

Subscribers:
ID
Email
Name

ListSubscribers:
ID
SubscriberID
ListID

Messages:
ID
Title
Content
ListID
```

So far so good... The problem is figuring out what is an efficient way to store sent and to be sent emails as well as email sending status.

For instance, I might have hundreds of lists with each one having tens of thousands of subscribers. To know the status of each mail, I would have to store the details about each message:

```
MessageStatus:
ID
MessageID
SubscriberID
Status (processing, sent, soft bounce, hard bounce)
```

With a handful of lists and hundreds of thousands of subscribers this can balloon to millions of messages in just a few days.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: As it happens, I recently added mailing list capability to a program that I write and maintain; I asked the customer whether she wanted to keep track of the email contents and to whom they were sent. She came up with a simple answer: send the customer a copy of every mail. This way, the customer knows both the content of each email and to whom it was sent, without need to store this in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking the question, I'll assume that the amount of space taken up by the `MessageStatus` table will be an issue for you.  You should challenge this assumption, however.

Given that you need to manage the space for `MessageStatus`, you could operate from the perspective of a ***work list*** rather than an ***audit log*** - unless of course you need to have an audit log for some reason.

To do this, use your `MessageStatus` table as you've defined it, except that when the record gets to "SENT" status, delete it instead of updating it.  This way, you only have as many records as there are emails that have yet to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

- List(table):
  ListID(PK),
  ListName
- Subscriber(Table):
  SubscriberID(PK),
  ListID(FK),
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  EmailAddress
- Email(table):
  EmailID(PK),
  ListID(FK),
  Subject,
  Content,
  SendDate

Comment: There may be a problem with this design: whilst one knows what the contents of the email were and to which list it was sent, one doesn't necessarily know who was a member of that list on the date the email was sent.